# Unable to Retrieve Custom Taxonomy Fields Using PHP

Tags: media, taxonomy-terms

I have added a custom image field to a Drupal 7 taxonomy called "field_uc_catalog_image2".

I am now attempting to get the path of that field using PHP with this code:

```
$normal_path= drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
$tid = array_pop(explode('/', $normal_path ));
if ( is_numeric( $tid ) ) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  print $term->field_uc_catalog_image2['und'][0]['uri'] . '<br/>';
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: und in eval() (line 6 of C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\le\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Whereas, this similar expression for the standard image works fine:

```
print $term->uc_catalog_image['und'][0]['uri'] . '<br/>';
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: try `print_r($term)` or `dpm($term)` if Devel is installed to find out what are loaded in `$term`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `print_r($term)` (as per Mohammad's suggest) I could see the correct expression was actually another one.

```
$term->field_image['und'][0]['uri']
```